# Measuring current drawn on a 12V barrel plug

Tags: multimeter

I would like to replace my monitor power supply it's 12V 3A and I doubt it's actually necessary -- old LCDs were pulling that current and this is not CCFL but LED. So I would like to measure the current drawn. The supply and the monitor is using a simple 5.5mm / 2.5mm plug, central positive. I would like to not damage anything in the process :)

OK, so presuming I have an extension cord (I do) I am ready to throw away, I guess I need to cut the cable -- does it matter which conductor? Just cut one of the conductors and touch the tips to the cut sections and done? Wrap perhaps the conductor around the tip for better contact.

Edit: so it seems my motivation matters and it got lost in the comments. A 3A adapter means it's an adapter with a separate AC cable. That's not particularly helpful for travel, especially not when even my Lenovo laptop 65W charger is now available in a small wall wart format (FSP Twinkle btw). 12V 1-2A very small wall warts are readily available. I have yet to something in a similar small format for 12 3A. I am not sure why but such a thing is unavailable AFAIK. I don't want to haul around AC cables. And yes, hacking a *very* small 12V 3A adapter with a fixed IEC C7-Nema 1 plug is a possibility but what about not hacking? :)

Comment: What do you plan to do next?

Comment: The price difference between a 12V/1A and 12V/3A power supplies is negligible. The potential malfunctions and wasted time will cost you more than that.

Comment: It's probably worth adding if you have a multimeter and soldering iron etc. You're either going to need to cut the cable and re-join later or make up a male to female test lead to get the meter in series (assuming it's a moulded connector). Note that apart from price as mentioned it's not likely to reduce your power bill in any meaningful way.

Comment: I have a multimeter but I haven't touched a soldering iron in 15 years. The price is irrelevant, it's the size and weight of the adapter that matters, there are small wall warts for 1.5A and even 2A but none for 3A. Cutting the cable is a go -- I can find an extension cord in the spare parts closet.

Comment: Keep in mind that electronic devices will often draw a large surge of power at power-up. This is significant when there are reservoir capacitors of high value on the input power rails. While the equipment may draw far less than 1 Ampere under normal operation, blowing the fuse on the power supply when you power up your display isn't worth the trouble.

Comment: You do realise that a 12v/3A PSU means it *can* supply *up to* 3A not that it is going to be "wasting" 2A when the monitor only draws 1A. The monitor will draw the current it needs from the supply, you might find that running a 1A supply flat-out is less efficient (and reliable) than running a 3A capable one at 1A.

Comment: Keep in mind that your monitor's steady state consumption may be less than 3A, but it may consume nearly that full amount under certain conditions.  You may find that your monitor blanks, or worse is damaged, if you supply it with 2A during a time when it really needs 2.5A.  Depending on your chosen replacement supply it may turn off (ideal) but it's possible it'll simply fall out of regulation and drop to 10V or 11V (not uncommon with particularly cheap supplies).  Depending on your monitor this may not be good. There's a reason the manufacturer chose a 3A supply.  Just be aware of this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your description is correct.

- cut one conductor of the disposable 12V power cord. NOT THE 110V or 230V CORD!
- strip the insulation from the cut ends
- set the multimeter to it's amps range (typically 10A)
- connect the multimeter's probe leads to the COM and A terminals on the multimeter.
- plug in the power supply to the wall outlet
- place the probes on the cut ends, making contact with the copper conductor
- the multimeter will show the current
- measure current under a variety of conditions, startup, normal, full brightness, etc.
- crocodile/alligator clips make this easier

[image]  [image]
<sup>*From Fluke 77 Series IV User's manual, 2006, Page 8 & 2. - 
This meter meets CAT III and CAT IV IEC 61010 standards*</sup>

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a citation for the figure, please?

Comment: @Joe: It's from page 8 of the Fluke 77 Series IV User's manual, 2006. Downloadable from www.fluke.com and other places.

Answer (score 0):

The main trick with current measurements is that they need to made with your meter in series. You've mentioned an extension cable, but I guess you mean an AC one? For safety reasons and because the efficiency of the existing adapter will be unknown what you'll want to measure is the DC current.

Regardless of whether you make a DC extension cable for the barrel connectors or cut the positive lead and later rejoin the setup should look like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZsarq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For the meter you'll want to set it for the maximum current range (10A on most meters) and also be aware that for most taking current measurements it involves inserting the positive test lead into a seperate socket on the meter. Put the negative lead towards the adapter output for a positive reading, although for a digital multimeter it'll just show a negative current and not do any harm regardless of the direction.

Also note that as Anindo Ghosh mentioned in a comment a lot of devices have an inrush current when starting. That could be challenging to measure with a cheap meter although many better meters are capable of taking a maximum reading, so check your meter's documentation so see if your's supports that.

Answer (score 0):

Surely you have a [kill-a-watt](http://www.p3international.com/products/p4400.html) meter to hand?

Measure the Watts drawn on the AC side, first with the monitor unplugged, then with the monitor plugged in.  Take a guess at your PSU's efficiency, based on how hot it gets (hopefully at least 75% if made in the last 5-6 years), and then you can take a good guess at how much current the device is consuming.

Obviously this isn't 100%, but it will probably be good enough to give you a go/no-go regarding a 1A psu.